# MIN value of primary key return another column value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table and need the value of USER_ID for the `MIN` PK

```
CLT_ID    PK_ID    USER_ID
  1         101      999     
  1         102      900
```

Expected Output:

```
 CLT_ID    PK_ID    USER_ID   MIN_USER_ID
  1         101      999          999
  1         102      989          999
```

I could simply create a rank function and then filter on my rank but is there another method? ie `Window Functions`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FIRST_VALUE` window function.

```
select t.*,first_value(user_id) over(partition by clt_id order by pk_id) as min_user_id
from tbl t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT T.*
     , first_value(USER_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY CLT_ID ORDER BY PK_ID) AS MIN_USER_ID
FROM table T
```